# Bulls and cows - c language - comparing arrays

Tags: arrays, c

You helped me so much with the previous question, and now I’m stuck again.

I’m trying to write a program for the “bulls and cows” game. The game explanation:

The program has a secret 4 digit number.

The user has to guess the numbers.

If the number is: 1235 And the use guessed: 1592,

The number of bulls is 1, because the user guessed a correct number and the position of it,  and the number of cows is 3, Because the user only guessed the numbers.

I have to use the functions the lecturer gave us.

I’m trying to compare the arrays to see if there are common digits for one of the functions, but the output always shows the number of bulls is 0.

I’m desperate after trying to work it out for 3 days,

Thank you for reading and answering!

the function.h code:

```
//A function that gets an array of 5 chars and contains the random 4 digits:
void GenerateCode (char code[], int size);
//A function that gets an array of 5 chars and checks if the guess is valid:
int validateGuess (char guess[], int size);
//A function that counts the bulls (if the user guessed the number and its position):
int CountBull (char code[], char guess[], int size);
//A function that counts the hits (if the user guessed  only the number, not the position):
int CountHits (char code[], char guess[], int size);
//A function that prints the number of hits and bulls:
void PrintScore (int bulls, int hits);
```

the function.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "function.h"
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void GenerateCode(char code[], int size)
//A function that generates 4 random numbers into the array
{
srand(time(0));
    for (size=0; size<4; size++)
        {
             code[size] = rand() % 10;
             printf("%d", code[size]);
             
        }
printf("\n");
getch();
return;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//now i'm going to ask the user to choose his numbers
int validateGuess(char guess[], int size)
//A function that gets 4 chars from the user and checks if they're valid

{
    int again;
    again:
    printf("please enter a 4 digit integer (different digits)\n");
for (size=0;size<4; size++) {
    scanf("%s", &guess[size]);
        printf("Your guess is:\n");
for (size=0;size<4; size++) {
    printf("%c", guess[size]);
                   }
int temp;
for (size=0;size<4; size++) {
    if(guess[size]!=-1)
    { 
        for (temp=size+1; temp<5; temp++)
        {
            if(guess[size]==guess[temp])
            {
              printf("\nInvalid entry, the digits should be different. Try again: \n"); 
              goto again;
            }
        } 
    }
}
}
getch();
return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*int CountBull (char code[], char guess[], int size)
{

}
*/
int CountBull (char code[], char guess[], int size)

{
   int x=0, y=0, count=0;
   for (x=0; x<4; ++x)
{
    for (y=0; y<4; ++y)
    {
        if(code[x]==guess[y])
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }
}             printf("\nThe number of bulls is: %d\n", count);
    printf("hi");

    return 0;
    }
```

the main.c code:

```
//including the libraries to help me use scanf, printf, time and my functions.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "function.h"
/////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
/*//A function that generates a 4 digit number
{
char code[5] = {0};
    int sizee=0;
    GenerateCode(code ,sizee);
}
//A function that checks if the guess is valid
{
char guess[5]= {0};
int size=0;

printf("%d", validateGuess(guess ,size));
}
*/
/////////////////////////////////////////////
//A function that counts the bulls
{
    char code[5] = {0};
    int sizee=0;
    char guess[5]= {0};
int size=0;
GenerateCode(code ,sizee);
validateGuess(guess ,size);
CountBull(code, guess, size);
getch();
}
}
```

Comment: For one thing `srand(time(0));` should be called once only and be moved to the beginning of `main()`. For another thing, you can "comment it out" to make your debugging easier: the same randoms will be generated on each run of the program.

Comment: It is difficult to see the errors because your code is not properly indented, is fairly big and you mixed input/output with the calculation. Assuming the function `countBull` calculates a wrong result, I suggest to simplify your program and use a `main` function that calls `countBull` with hard-coded strings, e.g. `int bulls = countBull("1235", "1592", 4);` `printf("bulls=%d\n";bulls);`. Then run this in a debugger to see what's going wrong. (I don't know if the `size` parameter is supposed to be the array size 5 or the string length 4.)

Comment: In general I assume that the input and output should be in the `main` function and that the functions declared in `function.h` are supposed to do the calculations only. This would make the code cleaner and easier to test and would allow to reuse the same functions with a graphical user interface. I assume that for example `validateGuess` should not read the input but only check if the string passed as `guess` contains exactly `size` unique digits and return e.g. 0 or 1 to indicate if it is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a logical problem. The algorithm should be like this:

- Iterate over the user's guess.
- If the digit you are checking is a bull, increase bull counter, then keep looking.
- Otherwise if it isn't a bull, only then go check if it is a cow.

Something like this instead:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  if(code[i] == guess[i])
  {
    bulls++;
  }
  else
  {
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
      if(code[i] == guess[j])
      {
        cows++;
        break; // stop looking if found
      }
    }
  }
}
```